# How to find hadoop-exmaples.jar in version 2.4?

Tags: testing, hadoop

I just set up the hadoop environment on my Mac and wanted to try to test whether it was installed properly.

And

```
namenode -format
```

works fine, however, nearly all the online tutorials used "hadoop-examples.jar" which was in libexec.

My hadoop is the newest release, 2.4 and there's no such jar in libexec or any other folder. Do they remove it or this is not used for testing the environment anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hadoop-2.4.0 there is different examples available for each application,

For MapReduce rleated jar files,

```
cd hadoop/mapreduce
```

[image]

For HDFS,

```
cd hadoop/hdfs
```

[image]

"hadoop-examples.jar" not available in latest version; for that they add more `jar` files for different applications.

You can use if from Hadoop.